# Custom directive, how to define output

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create an angular directive which outputs the return of a web service call.

It is my understanding that I do this by specifying the template, like so:

```
app.directive("testdirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "<h1>Content</h1>"
    };
});
```

However in my case I am producing a more complex output, not just a HR.

Is this the way to go? To put all of the desired HTML into the template?

Comment: I'd suggest you put your template into a separate html and use templateUrl instead of template.

Comment: You ca use `templateUrl` to define an external file. Take a look at the official documentation.

Comment: This is all outlined in the documentation. It would be well worth you reading them since there are numerous ways to get a template to a directive